# ASp.NET MVC 4 RAZOR - Best way to create a search page

Tags: url, search, asp.net-mvc-4, checkbox, http-post

I have a  search page using MVC4 with Razor. Details as bellow:

- Whole page is divided in to two part.
- Left panel contains total 5 search section like search by product, search by city etc. Each section have check box list. So user can select multiple option from each section.
- Search panel is a partial view with a submit button. As given below

  @using (Html.BeginForm("ModelsList", "Model"))
     {

  ```
  <div class="ModelListSearch

   Panel" style="width: 309px; float: left">
          <div class="heading">
              By Budget

              <div class="clear">
              </div>
          </div>
          <!--heading-->
          <ul>
              @{
      for (int i = 0; i < Model.BudgetDescription.Count; i++)
      {
                  <li>
                      @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.BudgetDescription[i].BudgetId)
                      @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.BudgetDescription[i].Description)
                      @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.BudgetDescription[i].Selected)@Model.BudgetDescription[i].Description
                  </li>
      }
              }

          </ul>
  ```
- Action methods are as below

  public ActionResult ModelsList(int? brandId, int? bodyStyleId, int? fuelTypeId, int? 
            transmissionTypeId, int? budgetID)
      {

  ```
      // this is called when first time page is loaded

  }
  ```

  [HttpPost]
  public void ModelsList(NewCarSearchContainer searchData)
  {
           // this is called on click of search button
  }
- On click of search button search result is shown in right panel.
- When we click on search button it post whole search object (NewCarSearchContainer) to action method & we find out the selected item from this object & get data from DAL layer accordingly.

  This page is working fine **BUT problem is that URL does not updated as per user selected search option. I think as we are using post it does not update url.** We can not used GET as GET pass all check box item as query string header which has a specific limit.
  One option is using action link instead of submit button. But in that case i dont know how pass selected item of search panel to action method.
  We need to updated URL as per selected search option to optimize SEO.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look of Datatable Jquery Grid. Click [Here](http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/zero_config.html).

Comment: Already i am using it. Problem is related updating url as per selected search option.